# ODATA v4 batching - How can I process the request as a batch on the server?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, odata-v4

With ODATA v4 batching - How can I process a batch request as a batch on the server?

I have a client successfully creating a POST request of 1000 creates as a batch to my webapi endpoint. My endpoint is running C# and Entity Framework.

The problem is that the controller in my endpoint processes each entry individually and makes a DB trip per create inside the batch request.

So while it is one POST, once on the server, they are not handled as a batch.

Is there a way to handle the batch request as a batch?

Comment: AddRange? method

Comment: Won't get to use it, the ODATA Controller is just public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(MyEntity myEntity) - that gets called 1000x times. I need a way to override that behavior.

Comment: I added a SaveChanges to the batch handler and then added an if around the SaveChanges in the controller so that it wasn't executed if I was in a batch. This meant that even though I was running that code 1000 times, it was only actually hitting the database once, do you think that might work for you?

Comment: @TomDoesCode - How do you check if you're in a batch?

Comment: I've added an answer so that I can add a bit more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `SaveChanges` call to me batch handler class in the `ExecuteRequestMessagesAsync` method and then only executed the `SaveChanges` in the controller if the request isn't a batch request. This means that although you execute each of your requests individually, you are only saving them to the database in one go.

In the controller, you can check whether this is part of a batch by checking the `BatchId` property. There is an extension method (`GetODataBatchId`) in `System.Web.OData.Batch .ODataBatchHttpRequestMessageExtensions` to get this but under the hood, this is just getting a property called `BatchId` from the `HttpRequestMessage` `Properties` collection. (source code: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Batch/ODataBatchHttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs)

If you are interested in being "true to the spec" then you should save once per changeset rather than once for the whole request.

A good guide for this is available here: https://damienbod.com/2014/08/14/web-api-odata-v4-batching-part-10/